# MySQL BETWEEN Query on DATETIME formate

Tags: mysql, database

I am reading data from MySQL database.
I successfully read data where time is equal to given time by the following query (This returns me valid data from alldata table.)

```
SELECT *
FROM alldata
WHERE Time = DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Now I want to get data between a specific time frame, but my following query isn't working

```
SELECT *
FROM alldata
WHERE (Time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 5 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
LIMIT 0,3;
```

If you see it's the same method as in the first query. But it always returns empty set while I'm 100% sure there exist data in a given time frame.

Comment: This is a very narrow 4 second window of time.  Are you really sure that you have matching records?

Comment: You don't need the calls to `DATE_FORMAT`; they're superfluous, because MySQL can form date ranges using dates/timestamps.  But, beyond this, your query should be working, if you really have matching data.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I'm getting data in the first query i.e. one second window.

Comment: Not possible.  Add sample data to your question to make it concrete.  Better yet, add a demo if you can.

Comment: Time moves forward. Your BETWEEN should reflect that. Also, note the LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've replaced the chronological order in the BETWEEN parameters:

BETWEEN works from BEFORE to AFTER,
NOW() - 1 is ALWAYS AFTER NOW() - 5

Maybe this will work

```
SELECT *
FROM alldata
WHERE (Time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 5 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ))
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Answer (score 1):

the brackets should be alike this (not tested, but it appears rather likely):

```
SELECT *
FROM alldata
WHERE Time
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Comment: `WHERE (Time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')` definitely lacks the second operator for comparison. just flipped the `1` and the `5`, to make sense... else the timestamps to compare are in reverse order.

Comment: hurrah! Yes @Martin it worked. Thanks. Can you please update your answer and specifically point out this difference,

Comment: @Umair already added that to the answer; just noticed that the later timestamp was as the first position and not the second - while their order seems to matter. there still would be space for performance tuning, by ditching the `DATE_FORMAT()`... or even just using `NOW()` as the second timestamp.